# How to hide or invisible navigation bar in Android aosp

Tags: android, frameworks, android-source

Need to understand the how can we remove or hide 3button navigation from Android framework side.

In landscape mode, 3 button is not hiding. I could see the bounds value for eg ( 0,0,254,273).

Anyone having idea about this

Comment: What about setting the property qemu.hw.mainkeys=0.

Answer (score 1):

If you're building your own framework, you can change the file

> framework/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/wm/DisplayPolicy.java

and the method `public boolean hasNavigationBar()` to return false to hide the buttons. But beware, this will make the navigation buttons be totally unavailable so if you need to show them again, you will have to kill the systemUI service and change the hasNavigationBar() result to true.